# CRON Expression for specific time

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, cron

How to schedule batch class to run at specific time 12.30 AM CST Daily. How to make it run at CST Timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.schedule method uses your user time zone. So, ideally, you should set your time zone to CST first, or you'll have to calculate the difference. Once you do that, you run the method as:

```
System.schedule(jobName, '0 30 0 ? ? *', scheduleInstance);
```

Where:

```
 0 Seconds
30 Minutes
 0 Hours (12 AM in 24 hour form)
 ? Every Day
 ? Every Month
 * Any day of week
```

Comment: How can I set timezone to CST

Comment: @user70573 In Setup, search for your name, edit your user record, and choose the CST time zone.

Comment: I have to run this batch in production. How will I able to change there.

Comment: @user70573 You would need to abort the old job, then schedule it anew.

Comment: Thats completely fine but am not sure how to change it to CST time.

Comment: @user70573 See [this KB article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332378&type=1&mode=1) for setting your time.

Answer (score 2):

**Cron Expression**

Cron Expression syntax :-

`“Seconds Minutes Hours Day_of_month Month Day_of_week optional_year”`

```
0 30 0 ? * * *
```

at 12:30 AM every day

Comment: Thanks for the answer.